# Exclude some test Classes when building spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have a big java project and want to build test classes for several parts of the project.

I have the Context test in the Root package of my spring boot test folder.

```
-Test
 -Root
  -ParentContextTest.class
  -ChildContextTest.class
 -FocusedTest
  -UserPermissioningTest.class <- extends ChildContextTest.class
```

I want to arrange my test package like the above so when am building the project only the main context are tested and anything in FocusedTest package don't run.

FocusedTest test classes extend the corresponding Context when running the test manually.

Am using spring boot + maven.

Any help would be great.

Am using Spring boot Build in pom Like below

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
           <fork>true</fork>
           <executable>true</executable>
           <excludes>
             <exclude>
              <groupId>com.Test.FocusedTest</groupId>
             </exclude>
            </excludes>
      </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude Classes from Test using the according Maven Plugin configuration:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: This doesn't work with spring boot maven build plugin

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the [`maven-surefire-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) (as @simon-martinelli mentions) and added the suffix `IntegrationTest` to the tests I needed to exclude. In the end, the config I used was:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With `mvn test` it skips the tests

With `mvn -Dtest=*IntegrationTest test` it runs the integration tests